# Facebook getUser() function returning user ID after logout

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm developing using the Facebook PHP SDK.

I wanted to make it so that when the user logs out of Facebook, they will automatically be logged out of my website too.

I am using the following code to detect the session, using the session cookie:

```php
$facebook->getUser();
```

For some reason, the `getUser()` function still returns the user's Facebook ID, even after they have logged out of Facebook on their website.

Am I to detect the session first using another Function?

On the official documentation example [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php), is the following excerpt from their comments:

```php
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.
```

This lead me to believe that the session cookie for Facebook would become unset upon Facebook logout?

Kind Regards,

Luke

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have the same issue!

The FB PHP SDK saves those things into the $_SESSION!
You can delete them like this when your user clicks logout:

```
$_SESSION['fb_'.APP_ID.'_user_id'] = '';
$_SESSION['fb_'.APP_ID.'_access_token'] = '';
```

Although this is not the final solution, it works for now.

I appreciate comments and solutions on that!

Comment: But the issue here is when the user logs out from Facebook.com (on his machine) "You can delete them like this when your user clicks logout:" <--- which logout? on facebook.com? How can u trigger setting the $_SESSION['fb_'.APP_ID.'_user_id'] = '', when the user is clicking logout from facebook.com

Answer (score 3):

I want to give an alternative, in a way you don't have to handle session stuff. Although, I must warn you this is slower than cleaning up the session, because it relies on a new request. What we're doing in the code below is to check on Facebook if the token is still valid. Here it's:

```php
try {
    $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    $logged = true;
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    $logged = false;
}
```

In my case, I was doing everything using the JavaScript SDK, so I couldn't clean session on logout. But in my landing page, I was needing a work around to check it before send the response back.

If you're facing something like this, definitely a good solution.

Comment: If the facebook session is still alive with a cookie on your site, but you are already logged out on facebook, this will return $logged = true. I tried that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in php-sdk in `basefacebook.php` at `line 567`

```php
         protected function getSignedRequestCookieName() {
         return 'fbsr'.$this->getAppId();}
```

This method returns the name of the cookie the sdk is looking for. However, javascript-sdk uses 'fbs_' prefix. Change this to 'fbs_' and it works fine.

```php
return 'fbs'.$this->getAppId();}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$facebook->destroySession();
```

Comment: This unexpectedly doesn't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8348505/556493 for a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

To destroy the session you can also use:
        $facebook->destroySession();