# Logged out of Facebook but it still reconginizes $user

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook

All,
I'm using Facebook Connect (JS SDK) to authenticate a user to my site. I'm checking to see if a logged in session variable is set on my site before even hitting code to check to see if a user is logged into facebook. This all works great however, when the user logs out of facebook and logs out of my site and I try and go back to my login back it still thinks that the user is logged into facebook even though I know they aren't. How can I prevent this from happening? I tried to set autologoutlink=true on my login button but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always had excellent results when calling FB.getLoginStatus() and redirecting the user to the appropriate content based upon those results.  Three conditions (although for an app, the second two are quite the same in my opinion)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and connected to your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    //but not connected to the app
  } else {
    // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try that. Do you find it better to use the php sdk or the JavaScript sdk? Just out of curiosity

Comment: I prefer to do as much client-side as possible. Speed up server response times and lowers my server's network traffic to external APIs lower too. Only do something server-side where you need to worry about clean data to be used for computations and storage.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I want to get the users email address from Facebook and actually look it up in my database to get the user id in my database. Is this possible using this method or do I need to use the php version?

Comment: Please start a new question as that is off topic of this question.

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by @Madan worked for me. Since my application is ajax based, therefore I can't reload the browser. I run a setInterval() call back function every minute to check if user is still logged in to facebook.

```
setInterval(function (){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if(response.status ==='unknown' && FB_LOGIN==1){
            alert('Your Facebook session has been expired');
            member_logout();
        }
    }, true);
},60000);
```

it worked like a charm.

Comment: for further optimization, the FB.getLoginStatus() code can be triggered on $(document).click() event. This way it will not distract the users

Answer (score 2):

Always give second parameter in FB.getLoginStatus( callback, true) as true...this  is because facebook response is cached in SDK.  So use alway true param for current user session check.

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook->destroySession();
```

or u can go to this link

[Facebook getUser() function returning user ID after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302558/facebook-getuser-function-returning-user-id-after-logout)